# How can I format a date field?

Tags: acumatica

I have a DateTime field that contains the MM/DD/YYYY HH:MM:SS date/time in the database, but when I apply it to a PXGrid, it only displays the date.  How can I make it display the date AND TIME?  I'm overriding the DAC object with the following attributes:

```
[PXUIField(DisplayName = "Start Time", Visibility = PXUIVisibility.SelectorVisible)]
[PXDBDateAndTime()]
[PXDefault]
protected virtual void FSAppointment_ScheduledDateTimeBegin_CacheAttached(PXCache Sender) { }
```

Answer (score 2):

Try to add attribute [PXDBDate(PreserveTime = true)] instead of [PXDBDateAndTime()]

Answer (score 0):

A year later, I stumbled onto this because I had the same question.  Here's what worked for me.

```
[PXDBDate(DisplayMask="f",PreserveTime=true,InputMask="f")]
```